# How to convert clob data into date time format in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a code where I am extracting oracle table data from database into excel sheet and sending it as an attachment in mail. Problem is the date column of the table has been displayed as DD-Mon-YY format as I am storing data into clob. My requirement is to display date with timestamp.
 Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Simply use `to_char` with proper `format model` before fetching it into `clob` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you have the DATE value stored in CLOB type variable. And when it is displayed in the Excel sheet, you are not able to see the TIME portion. the issue could be -

1. You did not extract the complete DATE TIME value into the CLOB field.
2. The format model is overridden in the Excel file.

`to_char` along with proper format model should suffice -

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    dt CLOB;
  3  BEGIN
  4    dt := to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  5    dbms_output.put_line(dt);
  6  END;
  7  /
19-jan-2015 12:29:44

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Above, "dt" is a CLOB type, I have stored the DATE value in the following format `'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'`.